# Select and delete selected

Tags: php, sql

I am programming something like e-mail for my users. I want to allow people to select letters and delete selected. How can I do it? I can't imagine how can I do it only with one MySQL query. Is it even possible?

Comment: I think we're going to need to know more about what you're trying to accomplish. Perhaps a better description would help with examples if at all possible.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? I do not understand a single word.

Comment: @Pekka: my cents on a webbased email client like Gmail/Hotmail/etc. But his question is after all indeed too broad. Sounds like as if he is been thrown in a deep hole and trying to rely on others to explain stuff and/or do the work for him. @Donator: I'd suggest to learn all the separate concepts one by one, step by step. First get HTML right. Then CSS. Then JS. Then PHP. Then SQL. Then Mail. Then do the math.

Comment: @BalusC hats off to your ability to descramble coded messages :)

Comment: Dude, I just didn't know the function WHERE id IN, that's it. Don't be so angry. Good luck.

Comment: No hard feelings. It's just the language barrier. If you have phrased your question **to the point** like: *"How do I delete multiple rows from a database by ID in a single SQL query?"*, it would have been **much** more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "select" and "delete" you mean the SQL commands `SELECT` and `DELETE`, then you don't need to SELECT and DELETE at the same time. First run a SELECT to display the emails and to allow the user to choose which emails they want to delete. Then use the ids of the emails (usually a hidden field) to run a DELETE with a `WHERE id IN (..., ..., ...)`.

Comment: That is absolutely what I needed. Thank you very much. ;)

Comment: I think Jesse's comment is worth repeating here: remember to check that a user can only delete their own emails. Don't blindly trust the user's list of id's - enforce it by adding an appropriate check in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE $table_name WHERE id in ($ids)` should do your delete. in one shot. so you jsut need to get all the id's for the records which im assuming are somehow coded into your html as part of the id, class, or value attributes for whatever elements..

Comment: This will work, but it's difficult to parameterize that query properly to avoid SQL injection problems.  If you go this route, make sure to sanitize the inputs(make sure every value in ids is the correct type) and also don't forget to restrict the delete query on the correct user so that users don't delete each other's email.

Something like:
DELETE FROM Email WHERE Email.id IN ($ids) AND Email.user = $username

Comment: Jesse, I will do the same with SELECT, using WHERE IN. It is not a problem to check if person deletes his own emails or not :)

Answer (score 0):

It takes one query to list their email, but once you get a list of unique ids that the user has selected, you can run one delete query per email.